# jqGrid custom error message box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'd like to override to default error message box of jqgrid. 
When you click edit button on navbar but no row selected, jqgrid will fire error message box ("Please, select row") that in my opinion, not eye catching enough.

Is there any way to replace it so that I can use my own fancy message box function?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `alerttext` option of `navGrid`:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {alerttext: "Please, select row before to click on the button!!!"});
```

You can use `$.jgrid.nav` to change the text on all grids on the page

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.nav, {
    alerttext: "Please, select row before to click on the button!!!"
});
```

Comment: actually I don't want to use default jqgrid message box. I want to replace the standard error message box with my own message box syle.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override event handlers with setGridParam

Something like this:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ 
    yourClickFunction: function() { alert('my over written event'); }
});
```

See docs:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that I call for my Delete button:

```
    function deleteItemFromGrid() {
        //set the grid so we don't have to search the DOM multiple times
        var grid = $('#GridName');

        //ensure a row is selected
        var selectedRow = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
        if (selectedRow) {
            idRowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRow)

            grid.jqGrid('delGridRow', selectedRow, { url: '/Controller/DeleteAction', reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                delData: idRowData
            }); //grid
        } //if
        else {
            showFancyErrorDialogFunction();
        } //else 

    }
```